# How to read the pdf file in a line by line string in Python/Django?

Tags: python, django, pdf, file-io, readlines

I am dealing with the text and pdf file equal or less than `5KB`. If the file is a text file, I get a file from the form and get the required input in a string to summarize:

```
 file = file.readlines()
 file = ''.join(file)
 result = summarize(file, num_sentences)
```

It's easily done but for pdf file it turns out it's not that easy. Is there a way to get the sentences of pdf file as a string like I did with my txt file in Python/Django?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481945/how-to-read-line-by-line-in-pdf-file-using-pypdf

Comment: Yes, probably. But I already tried the suggest solution in that question. It couldn't return the content of all the file in a string.

Comment: Maybe you could say that in your question and say what exactly went wrong (error message ? wrong content ?) so we can help you !

Comment: You can use this app: http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html

Answer (score 3):

I dont think its possible to read pdfs just the way you are doing it with txt files, you need to convert the pdfs into txt files(refer [Python module for converting PDF to text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665/python-module-for-converting-pdf-to-text)) and then process it.
you can also refer to this to convert pdf to txt easily http://code.activestate.com/recipes/511465-pure-python-pdf-to-text-converter/

Answer (score 0):

In Django you can do this:

views.py :

```
def upload_pdf():
     if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
        pdfFileObj = request.FILES['myfile'].read() 
        pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(io.BytesIO(pdfFileObj))
        NumPages = pdfReader.numPages
        i = 0
        content = []
        while (i<NumPages):
            text = pdfReader.getPage(i)
            content.append(text.extractText())
            i +=1
       # depends on what you want to do with the pdf parsing results
       return render(request, .....)
```

html part:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/url">
    {% csrf_token %}
      <input  type="file" name="myfile"> # the name is the same as the one you put in FILES['myfile']
    <button class="butto" type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

In Python you can simply do this :

```
fileName = "path/test.pdf"
pdfFileObj = open(fileName,'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
NumPages = pdfReader.numPages

i = 0
content = []
while (i<NumPages):
    text = pdfReader.getPage(i)
    content.append(text.extractText())
    i +=1
```