# read a pdf in python

Tags: python, pdf

I want to read a pdf file in python. Tried some of the ways- PdfReader and pdfquery but not getting the result in string format. Want to have some of the content from that pdf file. is there any way to do that?

Comment: You can see at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481945/how-to-read-line-by-line-in-pdf-file-using-pypdf

Answer (score 0):

[PDFminer](http://www.unixuser.org/%7Eeuske/python/pdfminer/index.html) is a tool for extracting information from PDF documents.

Answer (score -1):

Does it matter in your case if file is pdf or not. If you just want to read your file as string, just open it as you would open a normal file.

E.g.-

```
with open('my_file.pdf') as file:
     content = file.read()
```

Comment: if the file is in pdf format, it will return some of junk characters.

Comment: Do you wish to render file or just read its contents for some purpose??

Comment: @hspandher i just want to read the pdf n then want to save some of the content of that pdf in the string format.

Comment: Then this should work

Comment: So what I'm saying is pdf is ofcourse encoded, do you want to 'read' the contents of pdf (by read I mean decipher), or you just want to save the contents to some other file or stuff.

Comment: In latter case, this solution would work

Comment: @hspandher the method u suggested is fine for txt file but when am doing same with pdf file it returns some junk chars ..