# How to click on the Search company name button,type company name and search using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, search, web-scraping

I just want to search the company name on the search button, type the company name and then it will open the link of that company if exist I tried a lot of ways and there are always problems. .new to web scraping

I have tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/RoshanB/Desktop/sentiment1/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver")

driver.get("http://www.careratings.com/brief-rationale.aspx")
```

but now I don't know how to click on "Search company name", type company name and open that company link using selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Tag

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/RoshanB/Desktop/sentiment1/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver")
driver.get('http://www.careratings.com/brief-rationale.aspx')
time.sleep(4)

companyArray = []

try:
    search = driver.find_element_by_name('txtSearchCompany_brief')
    search.send_keys("Reliance Capital Limited")
    search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(4)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    companies = soup.find("table",class_="table1")

    for tag in companies.findChildren():
        if isinstance(tag, Tag) and tag.name in 'a' and tag.has_attr('href'):
            url_string = "http://www.careratings.com/"+tag['href'].replace (" ","%20")
""" **Open pdf file in new tab browser** """
            open_pdf(url_string)
            companyArray.append(tag.text)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

driver.quit()
print(companyArray)
```

O/P

Company list:

```
['Reliance Capital Limited', 'Dewan Housing Finance Corporation Limited Ratings of various Securitisation transactions', 'Gamut Infosystems Limited', 'Henraajh Feeds India Private Limited', 'Ramdhan Spintex', 'Tripurashwari Agro Product Private Limited', 'Kalyaneswari Polyfabs Private Limited', 'Rakesh Kumar Gupta Rice Mills Private Limited', 'Sri Satnam Jewells Private Limited', 'Pitambara Foods', 'Sujata Udit Builders Private Limited', 'Kavita Industries', 'Krishna Industries', 'Pallavi Motors Private Limited', 'Anjani Cotgin', 'Sarala Foods Private Limited', 'B.M. Enterprises', 'Bihani Agro Foods Private Limited', 'M V Agrotech Private Limited', 'J.S.R & Company', 'ARG Royal Ensign Developers Private Limited', 'Ranergy Solutions Private Limited', 'RSI Switchgear Private Limited', 'Jyoti Chandrashekhar Bawankule', 'Sadguru Engineers & Allied Services Private Limited', 'R B Rungta Steels & Food Products Private Limited', 'V. N. Marketing', 'Aussee Oats India Limited', 'Dewan Housing Finance Corporation Limited', 'Dewan Housing Finance Corporation Limited', 'Dewan Housing Finance Corporation Limited', 'Dewan Housing Finance Corporation Limited', 'Dewan Housing Finance Corporation Limited', 'Dewan Housing Finance Corporation Limited', 'Dewan Housing Finance Corporation Limited', 'Dewan Housing Finance Corporation Limited', 'Dewan Housing Finance Corporation Limited', 'Dewan Housing Finance Corporation Limited', 'Dewan Housing Finance Corporation Limited', 'Dewan Housing Finance Corporation Limited', 'Dewan Housing Finance Corporation Limited', 'Pacific Medical University', 'S. K. Pradhan Construction Company Private Limited', 'Stadmed Private Limited', 'Namra Finance Limited', 'S Kumars Associates', 'R. R. and Company Private Limited']
```

if you want to **scrape** company name, need to install **BeautifulSoup** package

```
pip install beautifulsoup4==4.7.1
```

Where:

**txtSearchCompany_brief** is input search name

**table1** is search results table class

**Download pdf file link:**

[Chromedriver, Selenium - Automate downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894071/chromedriver-selenium-automate-downloads)

**Read pdf file link:**

[How to read line by line in pdf file using PyPdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481945/how-to-read-line-by-line-in-pdf-file-using-pypdf)

**Open pdf file in a new tab:**

```
def open_pdf(url_string):
    driver1 = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/RoshanB/Desktop/sentiment1/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver")
    driver1.get(url_string)
```

Comment: How to open the pdf of company name after submit button?

Comment: i  want to give date range also beacuse it open the pdf of 2017

search1=driver.find_element_by_id('txtfromdate')
search1.send_keys("2019-05-17")
search2=driver.find_element_by_id('txttodate')
search2.send_keys("2019-05-20")

search=driver.find_element_by_name('txtSearchCompany_brief')

search.send_keys("Reliance Capital Limited")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(4)



but in this it shows error...can you please check how to give date range also

Comment: and one more thing in your code everytime it opens the pdf link of only one company i.e "Reliance Capital Limited"

Comment: @Roshan I updated the answer for last comment, open pdf file in new tab.

Comment: @Roshan try your self to resolve date range issue because we are here to resolve small code or syntax error related issue, not for writing a full script.

Comment: okay Bharat I will update my solution also with the date range here

Comment: hey@bharat the pdf of the company is different from the search company

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, I have tried with id locator :

```
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("http://www.careratings.com/brief-rationale.aspx")


search_company = driver.find_element_by_id("txtSearchCompany_brief")
search_company.send_keys("Abc India Limited:")

submit_button = driver.find_element_by_id("btn_submit").click()
submit_button.click()
```

Though, you would have to write the code if company name is not available.

Comment: How to click on the date range of last two days, give date range like from (2019-05-17 to 2019-05-19) than search company name from a list (like Ramdhan Spintex,Axis bank limited) if it exist than it will open the link search,open pdf and extract the rating1 and rating action and update into my own excel

from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/RoshanB/Desktop/sentiment1/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver")

driver.get("http://www.careratings.com/brief-rationale.aspx")


using the above link

Comment: @Roshan : Try something, if things don't work out for you then ask. We can't write whole script to you. It's just unfair to us.

Comment: driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:/User/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver")
driver.get('http://www.careratings.com/brief-rationale.aspx')
companyArray = []
search=driver.find_element_by_id('txtfromdate')
search.send_keys("2019-05-17")
search1=driver.find_element_by_id('txttodate')
search1.send_keys("2019-05-20")
submit_button=driver.find_element_by_id("btn_submit").click()
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
companies =soup.find("table",class_="table1")
for tag in companies.findChildren():
        if isinstance(tag, Tag) and tag.name in 'a':
            print(tag.text)

Comment: can somebody please help in this